# How to set mainClass in pom.xml, maven jar plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have a pom.xml file like in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Buy-Binance-new-listings-on-Gateio</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gate</groupId>
            <artifactId>gate-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.25.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20201115</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- this goes within <build> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <!-- here we specify that we want to use the main method within the App class -->
                            <mainClass>StrategyExecution.java</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- other properties -->
    </build>

</project>
```

no matter how I set the mainClass I get the following error: "Error: Could not find or load main class StrategyExecution.java" after executing the following commands in terminal

1. mvn clean package
2. java -jar target/Buy-Binance-new-listings-on-Gateio-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

my project looks like this [project structure ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsJtl.png). I can run the StrategyExecution perfectly without using the terminal(if I simply click run in the IDE), the error exists if I try to run in the terminal. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: A main class is a class name with the complete package name and without the file extention. It is not a file name

Comment: 1. (Try) Use "fully qualified name" 2. Without extension (so no `.java|.class`) ..so:`<mainClass>com.my.StrategyExecution</mainClass>` (where `com.my.` would be the package)

Comment: ..looking at your (not existent) package structure, we can also try the (discouraged) "default package": `<mainClass>StrategyExecution</mainClass>`

Comment: I tried both suggestions, neither of them worked. The jar file is red as seen on the screenshot. Does it have anything to do with that?